# Can List.Distinct() apply to the list type of List<List<String>>?

Tags: c#, list

```
List<List<String>> ls = new List<List<String>>();

List<String> l1 = new List<String>();
l1.Add("Peter");
l1.Add("123");
ls.Add(l1);

List<String> l2 = new List<String>();
l2.Add("Peter");
l2.Add("123");
ls.Add(l2);

ls = ls.Distinct().ToList();
```

I suppose there are only one element in ls, but actually there are still 2 elements. What are the possible reasons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your case, you have to build the custom comparer to implement the interface `IEqualityComparer<List<string>>`, and use `SequenceEqual` to compare in `Equal` method:

```
public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<string> x, List<string> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> obj)
    {
        int hashCode = 0;
        foreach (string str in obj)
        {
            hashCode ^= str.GetHashCode();
        }

        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
ls = ls.Distinct(new CustomComparer()).ToList();
```

Another *tricky way* to distinct by using `GroupBy`:

```
       ls = ls.GroupBy(x => string.Join("", x))
              .Select(g => g.First())
              .ToList();
```

Comment: How about checking the reference first, and perform `SequenceEqual` only when it returns false?

Comment: The *tricky way* can return false positives, e.g. for collections: `{"aa", "bb"} and `{"a", "abb" }`. And it returns a string, not `List<string>`

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: That's is why I called *tricky way* it's just correct in OP question, for your case, we can use different separator.

Answer (score 6):

That's because `List<T>` has no `Equals` and `GetHashCode` implemented, so standard reference comparison is being performed. And it returns false, because you have two separated lists.

You can write your own `IEqualityComparer<List<string>>` implementation and provide it as [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) method parameter. Within the comparer you can use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx)) method to check if lists has the same content.

Comment: Obligatory [docs to the overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The Comparison used by List is based on reference comparison. Since the 2 lists are different instances, they are not the same and distinct considers them to be different.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the distinct values, you can use `.SelectMany()` to select the strings in each list within the parent list:

```
var list = new List<List<String>>();

var list1 = new List<String>();
list1.Add("Peter");
list1.Add("123");
list.Add(list1);

var list2 = new List<String>();
list2.Add("Peter");
list2.Add("123");
list.Add(list2);

var distinct = list.SelectMany(x => x).Distinct().ToList();

distinct.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: This is actually a slightly different interpretation of the question. Your solution returns a `List<string>` of unique strings instead of a `List<List<string>>` of unique `List<string>`s.